# Is it possible to trigger a mui dialog actions button with CTRL + S?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I want my users to be able to save using CTRL + S in a MuI dialog.

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using keycodes.

Note that you might want to consider COMMAND+S for macOS users aswell.

```js
function checkForInput(e) {
      var evtobj = window.event? event : e
      if (evtobj.keyCode == 83 && evtobj.ctrlKey) console.log("Pressed CTRL+S")
}

document.onkeydown = checkForInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

In a typical Material-UI (MUI) application, the dialog actions button is usually triggered by clicking on it with a mouse or tapping on it on a touch-enabled device. However, you can customize the behavior of your MUI dialog to respond to keyboard events, including CTRL + S, by using JavaScript event listeners.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import Button from '@mui/material/Button';

import Dialog from '@mui/material/Dialog';

import DialogActions from '@mui/material/DialogActions';

import DialogContent from '@mui/material/DialogContent';

import DialogContentText from '@mui/material/DialogContentText';

import DialogTitle from '@mui/material/DialogTitle';

function App() {

  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);


  const handleOpen = () => {

    setOpen(true);

  };

  const handleClose = () => {

    setOpen(false);

  };


  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {

    // Check if CTRL + S is pressed (event.ctrlKey) and the 's' key (event.key)

    if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 's') {

      // Trigger the action you want here, e.g., close the dialog

      handleClose();

    }

  };


  // Attach the event listener to the document when the dialog is open

  React.useEffect(() => {

    if (open) {

      document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

    } else {

      document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyDown);

    }

  }, [open]);


  return (

    <div>

      <Button variant="outlined" onClick={handleOpen}>

        Open Dialog

      </Button>

      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>

        <DialogTitle>Dialog Title</DialogTitle>

        <DialogContent>

          <DialogContentText>

            Press CTRL + S to trigger the action.

          </DialogContentText>

        </DialogContent>

        <DialogActions>

          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">


            Cancel

          </Button>

          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">

            Save

          </Button>

        </DialogActions>

      </Dialog>

    </div>

  );

}


export default App;
```

We use the `handleKeyDown` function to listen for keyboard events on the document when the dialog is open. When CTRL + S is detected, it triggers the desired action (in this case, closing the dialog). Make sure to attach and detach the event listener appropriately to avoid unwanted behavior when the dialog is closed.